# Conversation Exception in JMeter tool version 5.5

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

default conversion to org.apache.struts.upload.formfile failed getting this exception in new version of jmeter tool.

This exception is occured in newest version of JMeter only and not the previous versions.

Tried with older version 5.4.3 and this issue did not occured.

Answer (score 0):

1. "this" exception doesn't tell us a lot, going forward consider providing the full [stacktrace](https://www.sentinelone.com/blog/java-stack-trace-understanding/) so we could at least guess what could go wrong
2. `org.apache.struts.upload.formfile` is not a part of JMeter (at least I don't see it in [JMeter Dependencies](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/gradle.properties#L58)) so it has something to do with your application under test
3. I don't see any breaking changes in [JMeter Changelog](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) for [JMeter version 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5)

So I would recommend:

- checking the logs of the system under test
- checking [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries
- capture the file upload requests originating from JMeter 5.4.3 and JMeter 5.5 using an external sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), identify the difference and amend JMeter 5.5 configuration so it would send the same request as JMeter 5.4.3 does. My expectation is that you simply forgot to copy the file you're trying to upload to JMeter's "bin" folder or something like this.